# Access Google local drive with Visual code

Tags: google, visual-studio-code, google-drive

Good evening everyone, I wanted to ask a question. I have some applications on Ubuntu, which I can access the My Google Drive folder. I wish I could do that with Visual Code. But when I need to open a file, the Drive directory does not appear. Is there a possibility to do this?

Comment: Is Visual Code installed as a snap or flatpak?

Comment: I have the same problem. Can someone please provide help?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I know what you mean but...

Instead of the built-in Google Drive support, I have always used `google-drive-ocamlfuse`. This enables you to mount your Google Drive pretty much like any other HDD/SDD mount and it supports a lot more features. See here for overview and links to documentation etc:

https://astrada.github.io/google-drive-ocamlfuse/

Comment: Ubuntu already provides access to google drive, without anything external. I can access all my folders, my question about applications accessing google drive directories. Because some applications already access it in case you need to open a file. But with visual code, I don't have that access.